# Inject Component to a table cell dynamically - React

Tags: reactjs

I have a state `data` as input. I have 2 components `TRow` and `TCell` to the construct the entire table (iterating through data to construct table). But my scenario here is each cell can have a different component, depending on the `type` in the `data`. `type` in this below case has A (or) B (or) C.

How to create it at runtime? I don't want to pre-import all components before hand, only import (using import function) the type that is used and use those. How do I actually achieve this? I am looking for some kind of pattern or probably a better approach to the problem.

**Table Builder**

```
export default class TabularBuilder extends Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            data: [
                [
                    {
                        rowspan: 1,
                        colspan: 1,
                        type: 'A'
                    },
                    {
                        rowspan: 1,
                        colspan: 1,
                        type: 'B'
                    },
                    {
                        rowspan: 1,
                        colspan: 1,
                        type: 'B'
                    }
                ],
                [
                    {
                        rowspan: 1,
                        colspan: 1,
                        type: 'B'
                    },
                    {
                        rowspan: 1,
                        colspan: 1,
                        type: 'A'
                    },
                    {
                        rowspan: 1,
                        colspan: 1,
                        type: 'c'
                    }
                ]
            ]
        };
    }

    render(){
        let tableRows = _.map(this.state.data, (row, index) => {
            return <TRow data = {row} key = {index} />;
        })
        return <table><tbody>{tableRows}</tbody></table>;
    }
}
```

Comment: you can use an external function `const Component = getComponent(type)` this way you don't need to import any of the components. Or you can Inject it as props `component={TCell}` and then `<Compnent data = {row} key = {index} />` , I think this is more common.